# How to use google cloud platform using API key for android

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I want predict something using machine model from android.
I updated my model to google ml engine and successfully predict(online prediction) from my server using service account.

But I can't predict from android using API key.(Since I don't have plan to use server)

Please let me know how to use API key to use google ml engine.
If it's impossible, what is the good way to do that?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! You may refer documentation for this.

Answer (score 0):

Simply input, yes

You should be able to use the API key to consume the service as the same as you do it from your server. Because it's just a client to access some GCP API

Furthermore, you need to provide more info. As in what kind of client are you using in your server? If it's glcoud API, you may not be able to use it the same in Android, or you need extra lib to support it 
A nature option in Android would be a GCloud Java SDK, but it's still up to your preferences

Comment: I want to use ML Engine API of Google Cloud Platform from android using only API key not service account/end user authentication.  It seem google don't support API Key in my case. In document, Only below APIs is available... https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys                                             
Google Cloud Natural Language API
Google Cloud Speech API
Google Cloud Translation API
Google Cloud Vision API
Google Cloud Endpoints
Google Cloud Billing Catalog API
Cloud Data Loss Prevention API

Comment: OK, it's clear now, GCP doesn't support API key for ML Engine, so that service account is your next option, which is more secure with the same granularity and it's easy to use

Comment: Is there no other way to use API key? For example, The Doc says GCP Endpoint API support API key, So flow like ... Android -- API Key --> GCP Endpoint --> GCP ML Engine will work?

Comment: I cannot answer this as I don't use GCP Endpoint API.      Bare in mind, GCP is growing fast to compete with AWS and other providers, the more you use GCP the more you will find this kind of in alignment, but it's also good news to users.   In the other hand, why are you so keen on API key? It's mentioned some limitation about API key in the Doc.

Comment: Because it doesn't require user to log-in for authentication. In gcloud console, there are options to limit when using API key. For example, I can set platform(android, ios, etc.), app package name, and sha-1 when making API Key. By setting these limitations for API key, I think API Key could become safe. But it's not working.

Comment: While a service account doesn't require login as well, and it's not necessary to link to a particular user before using it, also the key generated is SHA256 if I was not wrong. You can also practice key rotation via API anytime